# How to avoid menu_position conflicts when registering a page in WordPress admin?

Tags: php, wordpress

In WordPress, when registering an admin page or a Custom Post Type, we can specify the [`menu_position`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments). However, if two pages share the same menu_position then only one of them will be displayed.

How to avoid such conflicts in a multi-plugins/multi-devs environment such as WordPress? How can one check that a menu_position is not already taken?

Any value from `5` to `100` or even `null` can result in a conflict.

Comment: Maybe not the answer you want but I would just not specify a menu position in the add_menu() or add_submenu() functions.  This way its guaranteed that your menu will show up.  A menu that shows up is better than one that doesn't at all.

Comment: @Kyle thanks for your comment, this is also what I thought, however as I have mentioned in the question even if setting a `null` value for the `menu_position` can result on conflicts. See here for example: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/missing-menu_position-conflicts-with-other-plugins

Comment: I have found a [suggestion to use decimals](http://gabrielharper.com/blog/2012/08/wordpress-admin-menu-positioning-conflicts/) (e.g. a positon of `25.2` instead of just `25`). However, while that certainly reduces the collision probability, it won't avoid conflicts completely, as two plugins can still use the same decimal position...

Comment: I have tons of plugins that have added menu pages and none of them ever conflict.  This must a very rare case.  I see your point on trying to find a solution that makes it impossible for two menu items to override each other.  For me, when I develop I never specify that parameter so my code looks some like this `add_menu_page( 'My Page Title', 'My Page', 'edit_others_posts', 'my_page_slug', 'my_page_function', plugins_url( 'myplugin/images/icon.png' ));`, and I have never had problems.

Comment: Furthermore, in [the comments](http://gabrielharper.com/blog/2012/08/wordpress-admin-menu-positioning-conflicts/#comment-787404253) of the above linked article someone suggests the following method: `while (isset($GLOBALS['menu'][$menupos])) $menupos+=1;` to use the next available position. That could be posted as a solution but I didn't test it yet.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the best solution but to minimise the risk try using decimals for positioning :) instead of "3" try using "3.1", "3.2", "3.3" etc...another way might be to use a function similar to:

```
function get_free_menu_position($start, $increment = 0.3)
{
    foreach ($GLOBALS['menu'] as $key => $menu) {
        $menus_positions[] = $key;
    }

    if (!in_array($start, $menus_positions)) return $start;

    /* the position is already reserved find the closet one */
    while (in_array($start, $menus_positions)) {
        $start += $increment;
    }
    return $start;
}
```

to give you the closest free position to the one you want....You can read more about it [here](http://blog.happyplugins.com/coding-how-to-avoid-conflict-menu-position-in-wordpress/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As of WordPress 3.8, using decimals is the same as using `false` or `null`, which not only will ignore your desired position but can also cause conflicts. Regarding the function you suggest (given that we change that `$increment` var to 1) I wasn't able to successfully use the `$GLOBALS['menu']` variable, perhaps I'm calling it too early? Not sure but for now I just ended up taking the risk of my plugin interfering with another... :(